# MySQL: Select only some grouped rows

Tags: mysql

I have following database (small example):

```
ID | username | action  | points
1  | matt     | login   | 3
2  | john     | comment | 6
3  | john     | login   | 6
4  | peter    | login   | 8
5  | peter    | login   | 8
```

And I am not sure how to select and group usernames which have the same action (=login) and points higher than 5 (for all actions).

Expected results:

```
username | COUNT | points(SUM)
peter    | 2     | 16
```

I tried subquery, but did not find the right solution. Do you have any idea how to do it? Thank you very much for your help!

Sorry, I did not emphasize the fact, that all actions has to be `login`. So, results will be without `john`, because there is action `comment` related to this username.

Comment: Why not `'John'`? Has a `'login'` action and total sum of `12`.

Comment: Sorry, I probably did not explain it well. All of actions related to username has to be `login`. For username `john` there is action `comment`, so we will not count with this username. I will add it to my question, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT    username, COUNT(*) AS cnt, SUM(points) AS points
FROM      tableX AS t
GROUP BY  username
HAVING    COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN action = 'login' THEN action END) 
   AND    SUM(points) > 5 ;
```

or:

```
SELECT    username, COUNT(*) AS cnt, SUM(points) AS points
FROM      tableX AS t
WHERE     action = 'login'
  AND     NOT EXISTS
            ( SELECT    *
              FROM      tableX AS tt
              WHERE     tt.username = t.username
                AND     ( tt.action <> 'login' OR tt.action IS NULL )
            )
GROUP BY  username
HAVING    SUM(points) > 5 ;
```

But I think that with an index on `(username, login)` and one on `(username, points)`, this will be the most efficient:

```
SELECT    username, COUNT(*) AS cnt, SUM(points) AS points
FROM      tableX AS t
GROUP BY  username
HAVING    MIN(action) = 'login'
   AND    MAX(action) = 'login' 
   AND    SUM(points) > 5 ;
```

Comment: Thank you, all examples work! Is there any difference between your third SQL and this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16734217/2417280 ? MIN and MAX are needed or using only all results with `login` value is standard behaviour of HAVING clause?

Comment: No, that answer is wrong. It's not even valid SQL to use `HAVING action = 'login'` when you have `GROUP BY username` only. (unfortunately default MySQL settings allow this.)

Comment: Thank you! Now I get it. When you changed the order of login values, only your solution works. Thank you very much for detailed answer, it works well now!

Comment: Could I ask one related question? I added one more column `example` and except `username` and `count` I would like to have all values from row with highest ID. I tried subquery, but did not find the right solution. Thank you for your help! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ea49/3/0

Comment: Make another question - and don't forget to include the Fiddle!

Comment: OK, thank you. New question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799368/mysql-select-only-some-grouped-rows-with-values-related-to-highest-id

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an aggregation and a clever `having` clause:

```
select username, sum(points), count(*) 
from tbl
group by username
having sum(case when points <= 5 then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and   -- count number with points < 5
       max(action) = min(action) and  -- all the actions are the same and
       min(action) = 'login'
```

Comment: Thank you, but does not work for me. Even if I specified that it should work only for action `login`, results contained also username `john`.

Comment: @user3316 . . . Your question wasn't clear.  It said that all the actions needed to be the same, with "login" in parentheses.  I thought that was an example of how they could all be the same, because it would have been much easier to say "all actions have to be login".

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Still your edited answer would work only when using `group by username` and not `group by username, action`

Answer (score -1):

try this query

```
select username, action, sum(points), count(*) 
from 
tbl
group by username, action 
having sum(if (points<=5, 1, 0)) =0  and count(*) >=2
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7361e/13)**:

```
| USERNAME | ACTION | SUM(POINTS) | COUNT(*) |
----------------------------------------------
|    peter |  login |          16 |        2 |
```

Comment: Thank you, but we do not know that `COUNT(*)` will be more than 2. Number 2 is example that there are 2 rows with action `login` by the same user.

Comment: Yes, sure, but it is not initial condition, but unknown results. Maybe I did not explain it the best way in description.