# MySQL: Select only some grouped rows with values related to highest ID

Tags: mysql

I have following database (small example):

```
ID | username | action  | points | example
1  | matt     | login   | 3      | 135
2  | john     | comment | 6      | 156
3  | john     | login   | 6      | 189
4  | peter    | login   | 8      | 125
5  | peter    | login   | 8      | 165
```

I wanted to select and group usernames which have the same action `login` and number of points higher than 5 (for all actions). All actions has to be `login`. So, results will be without `john`, because there is action `comment` related to this username.

Related question: [MySQL: Select only some grouped rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734078/mysql-select-only-some-grouped-rows)

Possible solution:

```
SELECT    username, COUNT(*) AS cnt, SUM(points) AS points
FROM      tableX AS t
GROUP BY  username
HAVING    MIN(action) = 'login'
   AND    MAX(action) = 'login' 
   AND    SUM(points) > 5 ;
```

And results:

```
username | COUNT | points(SUM)
peter    | 2     | 16
```

But then I would like to add to results all other values from row with highest ID. I tried subquery, but did not find the right solution.

Expected results:

```
ID | username | COUNT | points(SUM) | points | example
5  | peter    | 2     | 16          | 8      | 165
```

Do you have any idea? Thank you very much!

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ea49/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(ID), username, action, SUM(points) as pointsSum, MAX(points) as pointsMax, MAX(example) as example 
FROM tableX 
WHERE action='login' GROUP BY username
```